# Incorporating the non-independence of 'Date' into a model predicting temperature

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, independence

I'm trying to analyse some temperature data, collected at 49 sites over a three month period. The data are in the form of a maximum reading at each site on each day. I'm interested in how temperature differs between sites, and want to generate predicted temperature values for days when I do not have readings at a given site.

I've run a two-way ANOVA with Date and Site as explanatory factors;

```
Max.Daily.T <- aov(MaxDailyT~Site+Date, data=iB)
```

but the data have non-constant variance and non-normal errors, so I've switched to GLM;

```
Max.Daily.T.glm <- glm(MaxDailyT~ Site+Date, data=iB)
```

If I leave date in the form "dd/mm/yy", R outputs the levels in alphabetical order. If I code the dates so R prints them in order, the estimates differ (it produces an estimate for my first day, 25/3/13, rather than the first alphabetical day, 1/4/13), but by the same amount (6.27 degrees).

This suggests to me that R is treating 'Date' (or coded Date) as a factor with completely independent effects of each level. Of course, in reality the temperature at a site on one day will go a long way to predicting the temperature there the following day. Does anyone know how to incorporate this into the model? My only thought is to use coded Date as a continuous variable, but I wonder whether this causes problems as the temperatures fluctuate rather than being a linear relationship.

Thanks in advance,
Andrew

Comment: Welcome to the site. Since you have repeated measures, your data will not be independent; you should look into ways to deal with this, such as mixed models (known by various terms). In `R` look at `nlme` or `lme4`. Searching for either of these on this site will yield a lot of information. You might also look into using a trigonometric transformation to deal with cyclic behavior

Comment: It's a side-issue, but don't you need to move away from GLM defaults to deal with non-normal data and non-constant variance? (I am not an habitual R user.)

Comment: Since I expect that you also have to consider autocorrelation, I'd recommend package nlme. It not only offers mixed effects models, but also lets you specify an autocorrelation structure. It also lets you include variance covariates in the model. However, if the main purpose is imputation a time series approach might be better.

Comment: Btw., you days should either be in R's `Date` type or integers. Personally, I usually prefer working with days since start of measurement.

Comment: Thanks all for the help, I'll have a look into your suggestions. @NickCox thank you, yes, I've solved that with a BoxCox transformation, just keeping the code to the problem here.

Comment: Depends how you are using it, but a Box-Cox transformation applied to "improve" **marginal** distributions will not necessarily solve the behaviour of **conditional** distributions of response in models.